# How register vue-select component in vue 3 options API app (no TypeScript)?

Tags: vuejs3, v-select, vue-options-api

I try to use [vue-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-select).

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import { VueSelect } from "vue-select";
```

Then on [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-select) the instruction is to register like:

```
createApp(App)
    .component("v-select", VueSelect)
    .mount("#app");
```

On [vue-select.org](https://vue-select.org/) the instruction to install is (in [codepen template](http://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/NpwrQO)) (adapted):

```
const { createApp } = Vue;

createApp({
  components: {
    VueSelect: window["v-select"]
  }
}).mount("#app");
```

The first one gives runtime error:

*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mount')*

The second one seems to work better but still results in just an empty page in the browser with warning message:

*[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.*

Both errors point to the .mount() part of above code.

Without registering vue-select this code looks like this:

```
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

and that works fine.

I use Vue 3 Options API style in this app.

What is wrong and how to solve this?

I tried different package for vue select: [vue3-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-select) but that turned out to require Typescript which I'm not using.

Edit:
Tried now:

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.component('v-select', VueSelect)
app.mount('#app')
```

that gives a warning in the terminal running npm run serve:
*warning  in ./src/main.js
export 'VueSelect' (imported as 'VueSelect') was not found in 'vue-select' (possible exports: default)*

Then the site shows up in the browser however with warning:
*[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-select
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
at 
at* 
and the webpage shows no select element. In the developer tools however the element appears to be rendered, but not correctly, like:

```
<v-select options="[object Object]" label="club"></v-select>
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed the beta, i.e `npm install vue-select@beta`?

Comment: Most likely, you installed the `3.x` version, which is for Vue 2. You have to install `4.x` version (`vue-select@beta`).

Comment: I installed vue-select@beta